# angular: observe projected input disabled attribute

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-content-projection

I'm looking for a way to get the `disabled` attribute of the projected with `<ng-content>` `input`. For being able to change the host element's behavior accordingly.

```
    <host-cmp>
      <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="value" [disabled]="condition">
    </host-cmp>
```

Also, I don't think it's a good idea to repeat `condition` as an `@Input` for `<host-cmp>`, even if it makes life much easier...

The solution I've ended up with (so far, searching a lot...) is the following:

1. Create a directive for input, get attribute with `MutationObserver`
2. Grab this directive with `@ContentChild` inside the host.

```
// in <host-cmp>

@ContentChild(InputRefDirective, {static: false}) input: InputRefDirective;

get disabled() {
  return this.input.disabled;
}


// InputRefDirective

@Directive({
  selector: 'input[type=checkbox]'
})
export class InputRefDirective implements OnDestroy {
  public disabled: boolean;
  private observer: MutationObserver;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    this.observer = new MutationObserver(([record]) =>
      this.disabled = (record.target as HTMLInputElement).disabled);
    this.observer.observe(this.el.nativeElement, {
      attributeFilter: ['disabled'],
      childList: false,
      subtree: false
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.observer.disconnect();
  }
}
```

It works perfectly fine, but I have doubts... Isn't it too "heavy" for the task like this?
Maybe, I've missed something and this could be done in a more Angular-ish way?